# How do I make the Second Navbar Menu Sticky Work Correctly?

Tags: javascript, navbar, sticky

Hello for my website I want the second white menu bar to move to the top middle and stay at top when I start to scroll down. I followed a tutorial on how to do this but for some reason, it moves to the far left and does not expand all the way across. (Made the navbar turn red for testing purposes.)

Im very new to javascript so please take it easy on me.  :)

This is the website Im working on.
http://lonestarwebandgraphics.com/

```js
    const nav = document.querySelector('.header-menu_wrap');
    const topOfNav = nav.offsetTop;
    
    function fixNav() {
    
        if (window.scrollY >= topOfNav) {
            document.body.style.paddingTop = nav.offsetHeight + 'px';
            document.body.classList.add('fixed-nav');
        } else {
    
            document.body.style.paddingTop = 0;
            document.body.classList.remove('fixed-nav');
    
        }
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('scroll', fixNav);
    
    // 135 140
```

```css
    .fixed-nav .header-menu_wrap .header-container_wrap  {
        position: fixed;
        box-shadow: 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        background: red;
    }
```

```html
     <!-- Bottom White header START-->
            <nav class="header-menu_wrap">
                <div class="header-container_wrap container">
                    <div class="header-container__flex">
                        <div class="header_caption">
                            <!-- MENU -->
                            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation stuckMenu" role="navigation">
                                <!-- HAMBURGER BARS -->
                                <!-- <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="main-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <i class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="main-menu8" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                                    </i>
                                </button> -->
                                <!-- HAMBURGER BARS END -->
                                <!-- MENU START -->
                                <ul class="menu" id="main-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#photo-gallery">PHOTO GALLERY</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#video-example">VIDEO EXAMPLE</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#contacts">CONTACTS</a></li>

                                </ul>
                                <!-- MENU START END -->
                                <!-- SEARCH ICON -->
                                <div class="header__search">
                                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: I edited your original post to include the code as an snipplet, and added return lines at the end (currently is not yet visible). But I summarize the results: it works XD.

Answer (score 0):

In the page that you provide there are a couple of issues: first if you decouple a part of the page, usually it is a good idea to left something behind to hold height. Secondly there is an issue with z-indexes. Finally it is a good idea to read the coordinates of elements when you receive the onready/onload event, and not before, because page layout can change or can be innaccesible, I talk about:

```
const nav = document.querySelector('.header-menu_wrap');
const topOfNav = nav.offsetTop;
```

As I commented in the main post, if I add your provided code in a snipplet it works for me:

```js
    const nav = document.querySelector('.header-menu_wrap');
    const topOfNav = nav.offsetTop;
    
    function fixNav() {
    
        if (window.scrollY >= topOfNav) {
            document.body.style.paddingTop = nav.offsetHeight + 'px';
            document.body.classList.add('fixed-nav');
        } else {
    
            document.body.style.paddingTop = 0;
            document.body.classList.remove('fixed-nav');
    
        }
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('scroll', fixNav);
    
    // 135 140
```

```css
    .fixed-nav .header-menu_wrap .header-container_wrap  {
        position: fixed;
        box-shadow: 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        background: red;
    }
```

```html
     <!-- Bottom White header START-->
            <nav class="header-menu_wrap">
                <div class="header-container_wrap container">
                    <div class="header-container__flex">
                        <div class="header_caption">
                            <!-- MENU -->
                            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation stuckMenu" role="navigation">
                                <!-- HAMBURGER BARS -->
                                <!-- <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="main-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <i class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="main-menu8" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                                    </i>
                                </button> -->
                                <!-- HAMBURGER BARS END -->
                                <!-- MENU START -->
                                <ul class="menu" id="main-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#photo-gallery">PHOTO GALLERY</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#video-example">VIDEO EXAMPLE</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#contacts">CONTACTS</a></li>

                                </ul>
                                <!-- MENU START END -->
                                <!-- SEARCH ICON -->
                                <div class="header__search">
                                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```